# meaning of yet with past simple

Tags: grammar

Are there any differences in term of meaning between these two sentences:

- maybe it was with the album orders which didn't get dispatched yet that's all.
- maybe it was with the album orders which have not been dispatched yet that's all.

does the first one  implied that the albums have  been sent now and the second one that the order will be sent pretty soon 
Why past simple and not present perfect?

Answer (score 3):

Your sentence as it stands has a number of other issues, so let's consider a simpler sentence:

> The album orders haven't been sent out yet.
>
> The album orders didn't get sent out yet.

In both sentences, the orders have not been sent at the time of speaking. If you wanted, as you suggest, to say that they hadn't been sent in the past but they have been now, you'd need to say:

> The album orders hadn't been sent out yet.

As for "haven't been" versus "didn't get," they are more or less interchangeable. The only differences, to my ear, are that "didn't get" (1) is slightly more informal, and (2) places slightly more emphasis on the (implied) person responsible for shipping the albums out.

Comment: +1 for getting rid of the pointlessly distracting text before and after the actual construction being queried!

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to this question depends a bit on which country you are in. chapka's answer is good and I believe it is correct in the USA.  However in the UK, and using the simpler sentences from chapka's answer, you would really have to say '*The album orders haven't been sent out yet*'.  To my UK ears, the alternative '*The album orders didn't get sent out yet*' sounds somewhat awkward, - using 'yet' in a past tense negative sentence tends to require the present perfect tense  (Although I suspect that may be changing a little amongst younger people).

In grammatical terms I think the reason for preferring the 'have done' form in the UK is that the statement '*I haven't done X yet*' implies a relationship to the present - because, presumably, I am still intending to do X.